# How to record audio when connected to a landline via Google Hangouts?

Tags: macos, audio, google-hangouts

I would like to record audio when connected to landline phones via Google Hangouts (on either my Macbook or my Android smartphone). Which software is currently available? Ideally, it should be free and available for either Mac OS X or Android smartphones.

I could find some recording software when connected to others via video chat, but I'm specifically interested in recording audio when connected to landline phones.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are on the computer and you are using Hangouts to call land line phones? Or are you on the land line phone and are being called by a Hangouts user?

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I'm on the computer (or android smartphone) and calling landlines from there via Google Hangouts.

Comment: Note that depending on where you live, it may be illegal to record phone conversations without the consent of your conversation partner.

Comment: Does this work for you? http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/25/record-system-audio-mac-os-x-soundflower/ or http://justinh.org/2013/08/07/how-to-record-skype-calls-for-free-on-a-mac/?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on the computer (or mobile), it shouldn't really matter who the person on the other end of the phone is. The same software that records video also records audio, then using a tool such as VLC or ffmpeg, you should be able to extract just the audio from the file and discard the video.

This string is an example of the command for ffmpeg to extract the audio from a supported video format (found via google here https://peppoj.net/2010/09/how-to-extract-audio-from-video-using-ffmpeg/):

```
ffmpeg -i “whatever.format” -vn -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 320k -f mp3 output.mp3
```

For Android, there are various screen-cap programs which will work just the same, which might or might not require root. Non-root options appear to generally require USB debugging and a host computer to actually capture the video and audio (which you'd then feed through ffmpeg as above).

UPDATED with general software information:

First, software requests aren't encouraged because software changes quickly and recommendations are based on personal experience, which is usually specific and possibly not broadly applicable. You should consider a personal Google search to be your best place to start looking for the right software for you.

Taking that into account, I don't have a lot of experience with screen recording compared to some, but I use OBS to record my PC screen for broadcasting video game play. It works just as easily for simply recording to a file, from which the above command can be run to extract audio.

If you want to try for an audio-only solution, you could start with the VLC player, but I've found that to be temperamental to work with and difficult to anything more complicated than play video files, but the capability is there.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you point out specific programs for recording audio/video? Also, isn't it inefficient to first record video (say, for a 1h call) and then later extract audio?

Comment: Yes, it is inefficient, but only if you find a reliable and trustworthy audio recording program. As more people want video recording, you're probably more likely to find good video recorders than audio recorders.